# How can I host multiple apps under one domain name?

Tags: nginx, web-applications, dns, hosting, static-site

Say I own a domain name: `domain`, and I host a static blog at `www.domain.com`. The advantage of having a static site is that I can host it for free on sites like [netlify](https://www.netlify.com/).

I'd now like to have several static webapps under the same domain name, so I don't have to purchase a domain for each webapp. I can do this by adding a subdomain for my apps. Adding a subdomain is easy enough. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDmErvLJSnc) illustrates how to do it with GoDaddy for example. I can create a page for my apps called `apps.domain.com` where `apps` is my subdomain.

Say, I have several static webapps: `app1`, `app2`, `app3`. I don't want a separate subdomain for each of these, e.g., `app1.domain.com`. What I'd like instead is to have each app as a subfolder under the `apps` subdomain. In other words, I'd like to have the following endpoints:

- `apps.domain.com/app1`
- `apps.domain.com/app2`
- `apps.domain.com/app3`

At the `apps.domain.com` homepage, I'll probably have a static page listing out the various apps that can be accessed.

How do I go about setting this up? Do I need to have a server of some sort (e.g., [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/)) at `apps.domain.com`? The thing is I'd like to be able to develop and deploy app1, app2, app3 etc. independently of each other, and independently of the apps subdomain. Each of these apps will probably be hosted by netlify or something similar.

Maybe there's an obvious answer to this issue, but I have no idea how to go about it at the moment. I would appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: Consider asking on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ instead, but consider that questions asking "what's the *best* way to do X" are opinion-based and thus off-topic across the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initially solved this problem using nginx. But, I was very unhappy with that because I needed to pay for a server, and needed to set up the architecture for it etc.

The easiest way to do this, that I know of today, is to make use of URL rewrites. E.g. [Netlify rewrites](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/), [Next.js rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites).

Rewrites allow you to map an incoming request path to a different destination path.

[Here](https://github.com/bluprince13/bluprince13-next/blob/694bd51310850d6a81622c4153e9db4d3e0e6443/next.config.js#L7-L33) is an example usage in my website.

Answer (score 4):

Something along the lines of below should get you started if you decide to use nginx. This is a very basic setup. You may need to tweak it quite a bit to suit your requirements.

`apps.domain.com` will serve index.html from `/var/www`

`apps.domain.com/app1` will server index.html from `/var/www/app1`

`apps.domain.com/app2` will server index.html from `/var/www/app2`

`apps.domain.com/app3` will server index.html from `/var/www/app3`

```
http {
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile            on;
  tcp_nopush          on;
  tcp_nodelay         on;
  keepalive_timeout   65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type        application/octet-stream;
  index               index.html;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

  server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  apps.domain.com;
    root         /var/www;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {

    }

    location /app1 {

    }

    location /app2 {

    }

    location /app3 {

    }    

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one addition: if you're hosting the apps on an external server you might want to setup nginx and use the proxy plugin to forward incoming requests from your nginx installation to the external webserver:

```
web-browser -> nginx -> external-web-server
```

And for the location that needs to be forwarded:

```
location /app1 {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_pass https://url-of-external-webserver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you're asking the question prematurely — what actual issues are you having when doing what you're trying to do using the naive approach?!

It is generally the best idea to have each app run on its own domain or subdomain; this is done to prevent XSS attacks, where vulnerability in one of your apps may result in your whole domain becoming vulnerable.  This is because security features are generally implemented in the browser on a per-domain basis, where it is presumed that the whole domain is under the control of a single party (e.g., running a single app, at the end of the day).

Otherwise, there's really nothing that special that must be done to have multiple apps on a single domain.  Provided that your paths within each app are correct (e.g., they're either relative, or absolute with the full path of the location of the specific app), there's really not any specific issues to be aware of, frankly.